# calculating histogram using rsAtomicInc in Renderscript only returns address instead of the count

Tags: android, histogram, renderscript

I am trying to write a program for histogram calculation. So i have created a random array of 10 numbers treating it as the image array in 1D. The following is my renderscript and Java code. I want the histogram o be returned as an array with counts of each possible no generated but it only returns the first address of that number encountered. Any help would be much appreciated!

Java code:
public class Histcal extends Activity {

```
private int[] image;   
private int[] luminance;
private float[] nettime;
private int[] difference;
private RenderScript mRS;
private Allocation mInimage;
private Allocation mOutlumhistogram;  
private Allocation mOutallocation2;
private TextView t1;
private ScriptC_histo mScript;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_histcal);
    t1= new TextView(this);
    t1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    image=randomArray(10) ;

    createScript();
}

public static int[] randomArray(int n) {
    int[] randomArray = new int[n];
    Random randNumGenerator = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        randomArray[i] = randNumGenerator.nextInt(5);
        log("Generated : " + randomArray[i]);
    }
    return randomArray;


}

private static void log(String aMessage){
    System.out.println(aMessage);
}

private void createScript() {
     int[] luminance = new int[6];
        int[] difference=new int[6];
    log ("i'm in createscript");
     mRS = RenderScript.create(this);

     mInimage = Allocation.createSized(mRS, Element.I32(mRS), image.length);
     mInimage.copyFrom(image);
    mOutlumhistogram = Allocation.createSized(mRS, Element.I32(mRS),luminance.length);
   mScript = new ScriptC_histo(mRS, getResources(), R.raw.histo);

    mScript.bind_gOutarray(mOutlumhistogram);
    mScript.set_gIn(mInimage);
    mScript.set_gOut(mOutlumhistogram);
    mScript.set_gScript(mScript);
    mScript.invoke_increment();
    mOutlumhistogram.copyTo(difference);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            log("generated histogram counts:"+difference[i]);

        }
}
```

}

---

the renderscript code:

```
#pragma version(1)

#pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.histcal)
#pragma rs_fp_imprecise
#include "rs_time.rsh"
#include "rs_atomic.rsh"


volatile int32_t *gOutarray;
rs_allocation gIn;
rs_allocation gOut;
rs_script gScript; 

  void root(const int32_t *v_in, int32_t *v_out, const void *usrData, uint32_t x,  uint32_t y) {
  int32_t lum=*v_in;
  rsDebug("present value:", *v_in);
  volatile int32_t* addr=gOutarray+lum;
  //rsDebug("present gOutarray address:", *gOutarray);
  rsDebug("present address:", *addr);
 int32_t rsAtomicInc(volatile int32_t * addr);  
   }  

 void increment() {
 rsForEach(gScript, gIn, gOut, NULL); 
  }
```

---

the logcat display where it shows the histogram output is the first address of the first time it encounters each number. Also I'm puzzled seeing how can 2 elements in an array have the same address?

```
  I/System.out( 1527): Generated : 0
  I/System.out( 1527): Generated : 1
  I/System.out( 1527): Generated : 3
  I/System.out( 1527): Generated : 4
   I/System.out( 1527): Generated : 0
 I/System.out( 1527): Generated : 2
 I/System.out( 1527): Generated : 1
 I/System.out( 1527): Generated : 1
 I/System.out( 1527): Generated : 2
 I/System.out( 1527): Generated : 2
  I/System.out( 1527): i'm in createscript
  V/RenderScript( 1527): rsContextCreate dev=0x2a14ea80
 V/ScriptC ( 1527): Create script for resource = histo
 D/StopWatch( 1527): StopWatch bcc: RSCompilerDriver::loadScriptCache time (us): 2942 
D/StopWatch( 1527): StopWatch bcc: RSCompilerDriver::build time (us): 3763 
 D/RenderScript( 1527): present value: 0  0x0
  D/RenderScript( 1527): present address: 706096640  0x2a162e00
 D/RenderScript( 1527): present value: 1  0x1
 D/RenderScript( 1527): present address: 1074179188  0x4006ac74
 D/RenderScript( 1527): present value: 3  0x3
D/RenderScript( 1527): present address: 0  0x0
 D/RenderScript( 1527): present value: 4  0x4
D/RenderScript( 1527): present address: 0  0x0
  D/RenderScript( 1527): present value: 0  0x0
 D/RenderScript( 1527): present address: 706096640  0x2a162e00
  D/RenderScript( 1527): present value: 2  0x2
  D/RenderScript( 1527): present address: 0  0x0
 D/RenderScript( 1527): present value: 1  0x1
 D/RenderScript( 1527): present address: 1074179188  0x4006ac74
  D/RenderScript( 1527): present value: 1  0x1
 D/RenderScript( 1527): present address: 1074179188  0x4006ac74
 D/RenderScript( 1527): present value: 2  0x2
  D/RenderScript( 1527): present address: 0  0x0
 D/RenderScript( 1527): present value: 2  0x2
 D/RenderScript( 1527): present address: 0  0x0
 I/System.out( 1527): generated histogram counts:706096640
I/System.out( 1527): generated histogram counts:1074179188
I/System.out( 1527): generated histogram counts:0
I/System.out( 1527): generated histogram counts:0
```

I/System.out( 1527): generated histogram counts:0
    I/System.out( 1527): generated histogram counts:-1879038464

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 1527): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 1527): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1527): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Answer (score 0):

-1-
I tested your code on API 19 and Nexus 5 and I see that difference[] prints are coming out correctly. My Java code is the same as yours, below is the script code with some minor differences.

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.clearvision.androidapps.clearview)
#pragma rs_fp_full

volatile int32_t *gOutarray;
rs_allocation gIn;
rs_allocation gOut;
rs_script gScript; 

  void root(const int32_t *v_in, int32_t *v_out, const void *usrData, uint32_t x,  uint32_t y) {
      int32_t lum=*v_in;
      rsDebug("present value:", *v_in);
      volatile int32_t* addr=gOutarray + lum;
      //rsDebug("present gOutarray address:", *gOutarray);
      rsDebug("present address:", *addr);
      rsAtomicInc(addr);  
  }  

 void increment() {
        rsForEach(gScript, gIn, gOut); 
}
```

-2-
I was previously incorrect. Below code is fine.

```
volatile int32_t* addr=gOutarray + lum;
```

-3-
Your logcat probably shows error because of the following

```
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        log("generated histogram counts:"+difference[i]);
    }
```

difference array is defined with 6 int elements, while you are looping till 10. This is a problem.

Can you recheck?

Comment: Hi I did the changes although I do not get the error now but still the output of my "difference" matrix remains same! I want to see the histogram count. Any suggestions how I may be able to view the output histogram? how can I make sure if the rsAtomicInc is working? I can track until that the code visits the same memory address as the address pointer *addr for same "lum" values. But if the gOutarray gets increamented by 1 each time I'm not sure of!

Comment: volatile int32_t *gOutarray;
  volatile int32_t* addr;                                           void root(const int32_t *v_in, int32_t *v_out, const void  *usrData, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
      int32_t lum=*v_in;
      addr=gOutarray + lum * 4;
     rsDebug("value increased before rsAtomicInc:", *addr,    gOutarray[lum]); 
     int32_t rsAtomicInc(volatile int32_t* addr);  
      rsDebug("value increased afterrsAtomicInc:",*addr); 

      }        
       
  that's my update but it seems the atomic function doesnt work I get 0 value all the time in the output for *addr value.

Comment: Reposted the answer. I previously used RSatomicInc a lot. It was working fine.

Comment: Ok I'm using API 17 could that b e the problem?

Comment: Can you check on API 19 first? If you dont get identical results on API 17, then that is something Google folks might be interested in.